# How do i handle the event for Hyperlink generated Dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table which displays the Dynamic rows from server side script .Each  rows conatins various values and the first row value 
contains the link such as "Show/Hide" when we click on "show"  it shows the sub rows  and  when clicked on "hide" it hides the rows.
Now the "Show/hide" is dynamic is such way their id is .where $i is dynamic value which takes (0,1,2..so on)
Now how do we handle the click of "Show/hide" for each row

```
var j=0;
$("#mylink"+j).click(function(){


})
```

//In the above statemnt I can handle only "0th" link and how do we handle the links for 1 ,2 and so on.........

Comment: Can you add a little more detail as to how you are generating the HTML? Are you not able to use a counter on the server side and just put the value in then?

Comment: @spinon- Iam generating Html dynamically and Iam having the Counter values for each link "mylink0"  "mylink1" "mylink2" "mylink3"
"mylink4".How Do I handle the event 'click" for any hyper link clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an ID use a class, for example:

```
<a class="mylink" href="something.html">My Link</a>
```

Then use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), like this:

```
$(".mylink").live('click', function(){
  //do something, e.g. $(this).closest('tr').something();
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will listen for events from elements regardless of when there were added because the events bubble up to `document` by default.  [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is actually binding a click handler to the elements it found *at the time*, so doesn't work for future elements.

Comment: This is what I've used in the past, but jQuery ninjas say that .live() is an inefficient method.. Any response to those claims?

Comment: @melee - Inefficient as compared to what, searching the DOM for new elements every time they're added and dynamically binding a handler to *each*?  For dynamic elements or large number of elements using a method based on event bubbling like `.live()` does is *much* more efficient.

Comment: @nick:Really Awesome and interesting

Comment: @Nick Craver I'm not really familiar with what the .live() entails, but I was under the impression that it constantly checks the DOM for that element. Is it best practice? I've always wondered but never got a definitive answer.

Comment: @melee - That's the `.livequery()` plugin which works differently...what `.live()` does is attach an event handler on `document` and listens for events that bubble (which they do anyway by default), when the event gets there it checks the target against the selector it's supposed to run the handler for.